# python http handler broken pipe exception

Tags: python-3.5

I have an http server that uses an handle with similar logic to this:

```
MyHTTPHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_PUT(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers.get('Content-Length', 0))
        if content_length:
            body = self.rfile.read(content_length)
            if not body:
                # socket is closed
                return
            # save body
```

but when the server is running it always crashes on:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/server.py", line 524, in end_headers
    self.flush_headers()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/server.py", line 528, in flush_headers
    self.wfile.write(b"".join(self._headers_buffer))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 593, in write
    return self._sock.send(b)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

when I return after receiving no body.

I understand that the error is probably because the handler tries to write a response to the socket that was closed but I can't put my finger on where I can catch this in order to prevent the server crash and just close the connection on the server side

Answer (score 0):

Well the stack trace points to the `end_headers()` method, not your own code. So what you can try is something like this:

```
def end_headers(self):
    try:
        super().end_headers()
    except BrokenPipeError as e:
        pass # insert cleanup here
```